# How to show generic dialogs created using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As I've begun creating all new UI-components using Compose instead of xml, I am unsure how to handle dialogs that are created in Compose.

Using dialogs *outside* of Compose only requires a context for dialogs:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context as Activity, R.style.PermissionInfoDialog)
[...]
builder.show()
```

This lets you trigger the dialog from "anywhere" as long as you have a context (yes, I realise how this can be misused), but as far as I can understand, for compose, I need a "composable view" to add a custom compose dialog? It's manageable when you have a specific fragment that can show a specific dialog, but if you want more generic one that can be re-used, such as:

- handle generic error messages and show error to user (from "all views/fragments/activities")
- request permissions in multiple parts of the UI
- etc.

then this becomes more cluttered.

In my specific scenario, I have a number of different fragments that need the ability to request permissions. The ability to request the permission (which requires that we explain to the user why we need it) is prefaced with a custom dialog. This abstract fragment holds this logic, but the individual ComposeView or xml (since this app is a mix of old and new stuff) that is needed (?) to add my Compose dialog to, is not known to the abstract fragment. Sure, I could have a function that let the abstract fragment request "somewhere to show the dialog" and let each fragment provide a ComposeView, but this - to me - feels unnatural and forced.

Is there something I'm missing and/or some "common practice" regarding how to solve this? I guess I'm looking for something similar (logic-wise) to the old solution of simply having a reference to a context (or similar) to show the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I wanted to solve, and I did find a solution. It feels kind of like a hack, but not too much. If you can use context to get a reference to the `Activity` you are in, you can use `addContentView` to add a `ComposeView` and put your Compose `AlertDialog` in there. Here is a skeleton of some example code to explain what I mean.

```
fun showAlert(activity: Activity) {
        activity.addContentView(
            ComposeView(activity).apply {
                setContent {
                    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
                    if (showDialog) { 
                        // your alert dialog
                    }
                }
            },
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        )
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Are there no side-effects when it comes to fragment transactions, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Please add dialog in compose using [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties)).

```
val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

if (openDialog.value) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        },
        text = {
            Text(
                "This area typically contains the supportive text " +
                    "which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose."
            )
        },
        buttons = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = { openDialog.value = false }
                ) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: But this would still require me to have a composable view to inflate it into, it doesn't solve the question in hand.